# When I'm Looking For the Visual Studio android Emulator Devices in Xamarin I Can't Find it

Tags: xamarin

I have installed Visual Studio Android Emulator , But Xamarin Can't Show The Devices That I had installed in VS Emulator in The Devices That I Debug On !
Any one Helps ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether the emulator is installed properly. Can the emulator start by manual trigger?
2. Check whether your app supported minimum version is lower than or equal to the Emulator. You can find the settings in AndroidManifest file.